# Slice a Map in Dartlang

Tags: dictionary, dart, slice

I need to slice a Map. I've got it to work like this:

```
Map sliceMap(Map map, offset, limit) {
  Map result = new Map();
  if (map.length < limit) {
     limit = map.length;
  }
  map.keys.toList().getRange(offset, limit).forEach((key) {
    result[key] = map[key];
  });
  return result;
}
```

Is there a more efficient way and/or a built-in way? I couldn't find any in the API (https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.21.0/dart-core/Map-class.html).

---

From aelayeb solution:

```
Map sliceMap(Map map, offset, limit) {
  return new Map.fromIterables(
      map.keys.skip(offset).take(limit - offset),
      map.values.skip(offset).take(limit - offset)
  );
}
```

Comment: Since the keys of a Map are in an indeterminate order, how useful will this actually be?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz for `Map`, the keys order is maintained. It's not the case for all maps like `HashMap` for example.

Comment: Maintained, but not defined.  You can't ask for a slice in say "increasing key order".  So a slice of such would have undefined and relatively useless semantics.  Probably best to step back and ask yourself "why am I needing a slice?" and work out a different answer that doesn't require that.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I have a map of 46 items. Theses items are set in a specific order; that order will never change. In my app, I use the complete map in some cases and I use a slice of it in others (i.e. items 11 to 20). I need "slices" and I need "key/value" pairs...

Comment: Just because you set them in a specific order doesn't mean you are going to get them in a specific order.  If you set the keys a, b, and c, you might get them when iterating in the order of c, a, b.  The order will be *consistent*, although we hope it will be randomized between runs, or else you'll suffer the same fate as a large security hole in Perl which was later fixed.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz this is Dartlang, not Perl. I'm getting the keys in the order I've set them. See the documentation here: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.21.0/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap-class.html

Comment: So slicing a LinkedHashMap specifically might be useful.  But slicing a Map in general suggests things that are not in general possible with consistency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my approach for what is worth :

```
new Map.fromIterables(
    map.keys.skip(offset).take(limit),
    map.values.skip(offset).take(limit)
);
```

With this you don't have to make the limit test.

Comment: Note that the limit is relative, so in your case it corresponds to (limit - offset).

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```dart
Map sliceMap(Map map, offset, limit) {
  return new Map.fromIterable(map.keys.skip(offset).take(limit),
      value: (k) => map[k]);
}
```

Comment: I think it's more accurate to change the name of `limit` to `length`.